# “Designated” time

Tags: vocabulary

Is **designated** acting as a noun or adjective?
I have looked up all the dictionaries, but to no avail.
Based on my understanding, **designate** is commonly used to appoint someone or give something a specific status, but I kept seeing people using **designated time**. Is this informal?

Dictionary.com

1. to mark or point out; indicate; show; specify.
2. to denote; indicate; signify.
3. to name; entitle; style.
4. to nominate or select for a duty, office, purpose, etc.; appoint; assign.

adjective
named or selected for an office, position, etc., but not yet insta

Cambridge Dictionary

1. to choose someone officially to do a particular job:
2. to say officially that a place or thing has a particular character or purpose:

Macmillan
1 to formally choose someone or something for a particular purpose

2 FORMAL to give someone or something a particular name, title, or description

3 to represent something in a particular way, for example with a sign or symbol

Comment: **designated** is an adjective formed from the past participle of the verb **designate**.  It is analogous to **painted house** or **broiled chicken** or **answered question**. A time that has been designated.  A house that has been painted. A chicken that has been broiled. A question that has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean a sentence like this one:

> Please arrive no later than the designated time.

In a sentence like that, the word *designated* functions as an adjective, modifying *time*.

Many verbs can be made into adjectives by adding an -ed or an -ing. Here are a couple examples, from the verbs *dance* and *fade*:

> The **dancing** clown entertained the audience.
>
> His **faded** jeans looked worn and comfortable.

Not every dictionary will list every variant of a word, or every give variant its own entry, but I've noticed that Wiktionary (which gets listed at [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/)), does a pretty good job with this. For example, going to the Wordnik pages, we can see:

> **[dancing](https://www.wordnik.com/words/dancing)**
>
> - adj. Describing something or someone that is currently in the act of dancing. (See *dance*.)
> - n. The activity of dancing (see the verb *dance*).
> - v. Present participle of dance.
>
> **[designated](https://www.wordnik.com/words/designated)**
>
> - v. Simple past tense and past participle of designate.
> - adj. Having a specified designation
>
> **[faded](https://www.wordnik.com/words/faded)**
>
> - v. Simple past tense and past participle of fade.
> - adj. That has lost freshness, color, or brightness; grown dim.

It's not informal; it's just English flaunting its flexibility muscles.